# Import xml product list into Magento

Tags: xml, magento, import

Just quick question, what are or where I can find names of products attributes of magento product catalog?

For example is description also field name in table? Is 'price' name for price field in tabel? SKU also?
I am sorry but i dont know in which table to search for...

Answer (score 0):

Sku is in catalog_product_entity.  Other fields are in catalog_product_entity_xyz.  For example, description is in catalog_product_entity_text, price is probably in _decimal.  You'll have to look up the attribute ids in eav_attribute.  Most of the attributes you need, should be in the flat table for your store.

It should be noted that you shouldn't ever need to reference tables by name.